# Communication between 2 different objects in 2 different QML files

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

I have one main.qml file and I have other "example.qml" file. When I push a button from "example.qml" file I want to change a text in "main.qml" file. I tried defining the source of the text. I tried send signal. I tried using loader but always came to a dead end.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Imagine 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

//main.qml
Window {
       visible: true
       width: 1080
       height: 720
       color: "black"
       title: qsTr("MY GUI")

    Text {
       id: deneme
       x: 100
       y: 400
       color: "white"
       text: "Trial"

   }
}
```

```
//example.qml

Item {
    id: difflock

    Rectangle{
        id: diffLockRect
        width: 1080
        height: 720
        color: "red"
        signal  mySignal

        Button{.


          onClicked: main.deneme.text = "Finally"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new qml named by *Example.qml(first letter should be capital)*
- Define in *main.qml*
- *Example.qml* can access the objects in *main.qml*

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Imagine 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
    Window {
           visible: true
           width: 1080
           height: 720
           color: "black"
           title: qsTr("MY GUI")

           Example{id:rfrnc} // You can also reach the other qml objects by using this id

        Text {
           id: deneme
           x: 100
           y: 400
           color: "white"
           text: "Trial"

       }
    }
```

**Example.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Imagine 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Item {
    id: difflock

    Rectangle{
        id: diffLockRect
        width: 1080
        height: 720
        color: "red"
        signal  mySignal

        Button{

onClicked: deneme.text = "Finally"
        }
    }
}
```